# Python multiprocessing : imported functions not ending

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-module

When trying to use the multiprocessing library (python 3.5) I'm confronted with functions that do not end. All appears to be processed but the (main) program does not continue...

My current setup is as follows:

```
# Main.py

import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
from dosomething import dosomething

csvfolder = 'data/'

data = pd.DataFrame([
        {'a':12,'b':13},
        {'a':2,'b':14},
        {'a':1,'b':23},
        {'a':123,'b':16},
        {'a':142,'b':14},
        ])

print('start')

result = mp.Queue()
dos = mp.Process(target=dosomething, args=(data,csvfolder,result,'dosomething'))
dos.start()
dos.join()
result.get()
print('finished')
```

And then in the dosomething I have defined a function dosomething that does following:

```
# dosomething.py
import os
def dosomething(data,csvfolder,result,name):
    data.to_csv(os.path.join(csvfolder,'test.csv'))
    result.put({name:{'data':data}})
```

It appears that the function is executed as expected but never ends causing the main program to stall. When ending the program I get following message:

> Process Process-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 252, in
>   _bootstrap
>       util._exit_function()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/util.py", line 314, in
>   _exit_function
>       _run_finalizers()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/util.py", line 254, in
>   _run_finalizers
>       finalizer()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/util.py", line 186, in **call**
>       res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 198, in
>   _finalize_join
>       thread.join()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1054, in join
>       self._wait_for_tstate_lock()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1070, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
>       elif lock.acquire(block, timeout): KeyboardInterrupt

Based on the comments I learned that the result.put() is (when using the actual data) a lot of time, becomes inresponsive. The result I 'm placing on this queue is a dictionary with 2 elements of which one is a pandas dataframe (of several 100.000 records).

How can I solve this?

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. It creates test.csv, prints "finished" and exits.

Comment: Edited the question based on your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`multiprocessing guidelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

> ... whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined.

Just swap the `Process.join` and `Queue.get` lines to get it working.